# How much can I trust ASP.NET Request Validation with Web Pages/WebMatrix vs. XSS?

Tags: c#, security, xss, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

I have read (and am coming to terms with) the fact that no solution can be 100% effective against XSS attacks. It seems that the best we can hope for is to stop "most" XSS attack avenues, and probably have good recovery and/or legal plans afterwords. Lately, I've been struggling to find a good frame of reference for what should and shouldn't be an acceptable risk.

After having read this article, by Mike Brind (A very good article, btw):

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/159/WebMatrix-Protecting-Your-Web-Pages-Site

I can see that using an html sanitizer can also be very effective in lowering the avenues of XSS attacks if you need the user-input unvalidated.

However, in my case, it's kind of the opposite. I have a (very limited) CMS with a web interface. The user input (after being URL encoded) is saved to a JSON file, which is then picked up (decoded) on the view-able page.  My main way for stopping XSS attacks here is that you would have to be one of few registered members in order to change content at all. By logging registered users, IP addresses, and timestamps, I feel that this threat is mostly mitigated, however, I would like to use a try/catch statement that would catch the YSOD produced by asp.net's default request validator in addition to the previously mentioned methods.

My question is: How much can I trust this validator? I know it will detect tags (this partial CMS is NOT set up to accept any tags, logistically speaking, so I am fine with an error being thrown if ANY tag is detected). But what else (if anything) does this inborn validator detect?

I know that XSS can be implemented without ever having touched an angle bracket (or a full tag, at all, for that matter), as html sources can be saved, edited, and subsequently ran from the client computer after having simply added an extra "onload='BS XSS ATTACK'" to some random tag.

Just curious how much this validator can be trusted if a person does want to use it as part of their anti-XSS plans (obviously with a try/catch, so the users don't see the YSOD). Is this validator pretty decent but not perfect, or is this just a "best guess" that anyone with enough knowledge to know XSS, at all, would have enough knowledge that this validation wouldn't really matter?

-----------------------EDIT-------------------------------

At this site...:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339(v=vs.100).aspx

...I found this example for web-pages.

```
var userComment = Request.Form["userInput"]; // Validated, throws error if input includes markup

Request.Unvalidated("userInput"); // Validation bypassed
Request.Unvalidated().Form["userInput"]; // Validation bypassed

Request.QueryString["userPreference"]; // Validated
Request.Unvalidated().QueryString["userPreference"]; // Validation bypassed;
```

Per the comment: "//Validated, throws error if input includes markup" I take it that the validator throws an error if the string contains anything that is considered markup. Now the question (for me) really becomes: What is considered markup? Through testing I have found that a single angle bracket won't throw an error, but if anything (that I have tested so far) comes after that angle bracket, such as

```
"<l"
```

it seems to error. I am sure it does more checking than that, however, and I would love to see what does and does not qualify as markup in the eyes of the request validator.

Comment: @All, I also found this very useful link (it doesn't answer the original question, but may help other future viewers for prevention against XSS in general).   https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: I don't quite get your point. If the input validation fails, you can set custom error pages to take the user to. What you call "ysod" is really just meant for development, not for production and by default IIS and your web.config is configured to not show it for the release configuration.

Comment: @Candide Yeah, I see what you mean, I don't have to use try/catch, when I think about it. It is just that that methodology works for my current page set up. I also know (unless otherwise told to in web.config) that the YSOD won't show the code to remote machines, but it is still ugly and I wouldn't want users to see the error that way (i.e., on the YSOD screen at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the ASP.NET request validation is fairly trustworthy but you should not rely on it alone.  For some projects I leave it enabled to provide an added layer of security.  In general it is preferable to use a widely tested/utilized solution than to craft one yourself.  If the "YSOD" (or custom error page) becomes an issue with my clients, I usually just disable the .NET request validation feature for the page.

Once doing so, I carefully ensure that my input is sanitized but more importantly that my *output is encoded*.  So anywhere where I push user-entered (or web service, etc. -- anything that comes from a third party) content to the user it gets wrapped in Server.HtmlEncode().  This approach has worked pretty well for a number of years now.

The link you provided to Microsoft's documentation is quite good.  To answer your question about what is considered markup (or what *should be considered markup*) get on your hacker hat and check out the OWASP XSS Evasion Cheat Sheet.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet#HTML_entities

Comment: Here is another link with an actual evasion technique for .NET request validation.  http://www.securitysift.com/xss-and-cross-site-scripting-with-a-little-help-from-asp-net-and-ie9/

Comment: is the method Server.HtmlEncode() a C# method (really a part of asp.net, I'm sure) that pretty much converts things like "&" to "&amp;" and "<" to "&lt;"? Also, one more question: The way the site was built (this may have to change) JavaScript is responsible for actually writing the third pary data to the page, so it is therein that I have the function that encodes ">" to "&gt;" and such. Is this potentially a security risk, as this encoding is handled client-side? (Again, in my case, it is not THAT big of an issue as only a select few registered users have access anyway).

Comment: On HtmlEncode, yes, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: On the fact you have JavaScript code responsible for your HTML encoding, I'm not sure it could be OK, it really depends on how it is implemented.  Personally, I'd be more comfortable doing it on the server side, but that doesn't mean you'd have to.  What is the risk?  I suppose if someone were to disable javascript the HTML would not be encoded but also would never even be added to the DOM..

Comment: Exactly. Simply disabling JavaScript shouldn't be enough to implement XSS, for the reason you stated, however, I think I am more paranoid about them saving the source to a text file, making changes, and then re-running their customized code somehow (I read about something like that, but not sure how that works, so, I could be misrepresenting that attack avenue). Again, though, this question is more (but not entirely) for future reference, as NONE of these pages are ever accessible by non-registered users, who, if exploiting XSS, would be easily track-able (unless further steps are taken).

Comment: Even if someone hacked the javascript, it would only affect their experience.  Other users would pull your javascript from the server.  The attacker would need to compromise your server (or something in between your server and the clients e.g. DNS poisoning) to push the hacked javascript to other users.